# Setup of Html string in Textview Showing Weird texts

Tags: android, html, textview

Hello I am facing one issue with using of html in my textview

I have one html string and i am setting up with below code :

```
tvDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString)); // where data.description is html string
```

it works fine sometime but in most of cases it shows some weird texts as a content in textview

here is a image: 
[image]

Here i highlighting aria that shows weird texts, I have also one questions about  this issue, Is this issue occurs because in response i am getting some character which not supported in textview or what ? please leave your feedback to solve this

Thank you in advance

**Edit :**

This string which i am getting encoded and decode with Base64 here is it.

```
String htmlString = "&acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133;     &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133;Android store's TOP1     privacy safeguard&acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; 
<p>Lock your privacy&iuml;&frac14;&#140;Free your hand</p>
<p><b>Why do I need this App? </b></p>
<p>The Most Trusted and Popular Privacy Protector for Android,"
```

Comment: What `is data.description`

Comment: `Html.fromHtml` does not support all HTML tags. Can you also put your original HTML?

Comment: data.description is a html string i have already mentioned in comments @MustansarSaeed

Comment: It looks like that html contains some tags or text which has some unicode characters which textview is unable to decode

Comment: I have edited with string content @tasomaniac

Comment: @MustansarSaeed i have edited with string content please check it and tell me

Comment: It just cannot see &acirc and &iuml. You need to provide numbered utf8 versions of them.

Comment: I am not clear with that would you please tell me how ? @tasomaniac

Comment: `&acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133;     &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133;Android store's TOP1     privacy safeguard&acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; &acirc;&#152;&#133; ` these contents don't making sense to me, what this mean>

Comment: @MustansarSaeed &acirc;&#152;&#133; something like special characters which i am getting in response and decode it with base 64